# Ejs double ejs tag in one line erorr

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, ejs

<% if ( <%= id  %> = 0 ) { %>

erorr :

Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".

can anyone please tell me how can add my passed id value in if ( after searching some while i have guessed the erorr that you cant 2 ejs tags in one line )

any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `<%= %>` this tag to access id value inside `<% %>` .
Just simply change this

`<% if ( <%= id %> = 0 ) { %>`

to this:

```
<% if(id == 0 ){ %>
    //your code
<% } %>
```